# A loop doesn't work properly

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class GuessNumber{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = 0;
        String num = "65854"; // This is the secret code
        String s;
        System.out.println("This program asks you to guess the code of 5 digits. ");
        System.out.println("You have 5 attempts. ");

        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
            do{
                s = in.nextLine(); 


                for(int c=0; c<s.length(); c++){
                    if(s.charAt(c)==num.charAt(c)) //if digit in 's' equals the digit in the same position in 'num', increment variable x
                        x++;
                }

                System.out.println("Number of correct digits in right position: " + x);  // here the execution goes out of bounds
            }
            while(!s.equals(num));
            System.out.println("Congrats! You guessed the secret code. ");
            System.exit(0);

        }
    }
}
```

I tried to create a simple java program which should allow user to guess a prefixed code of five digits (with only five attempts). The do-while loop shows correct values only for the first two attempts, then it goes out of bounds (shows values>5, which are impossible for a code of only 5 digits). Can somebody explain why?

Comment: *What* goes out of bounds, exactly? Where precisely is the error? Why do you have that `do/while` loop which is basically giving an infinite number of guesses? What do you mean by "values > 5" - there's no "values" variable. (Hint: it's possible that the only problem is that you're not resetting `x` to 0 when you read the next line of user input...)

Comment: `if(s.charAt(c)==num.charAt(c))` - `num` has a prefixed length of `5`, while `s` comes from user input. What will happen if `s` is longer than `num`?

Comment: You mean I should define limits for 's'?

Comment: @catzbro1 Yes. Your `for` loop uses `s.length()` as the upper limit, and you use the same index for accessing `num` characters. This means that if `s.length()` is `10`, `c` can go from `0` to `9`: `s.charAt(9)` will work as expected, but `num.charAt(9)` will go out of bounds, as `num` has `5` characters.

Comment: If you ask the user to "guess a prefixed code of five digits" then it makes sense to limit your `s` to a maximum of `num.length()`

Comment: @JonSkeet ok, now I understand, it's because of x (it increments after every attempt without being resetted). Thnx!

Comment: @catzbro1 No, the issue is not with `x`. You never use it to access a string characters, so it cannot give you an out of bounds exception.

Comment: this code is gonna run for **EVER** , because you have `do-while` that run until you enter the true number :))

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi there is a 'for' which limits the execution for 5 times, or am I wrong? xD

Comment: remove the `do-while` it is not neccessary

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. The `for` limits nothing. It will stay in its first iteration forever and if the guess is correct, it will be broken out of anyway.

Comment: no matter to the `for` limitation , your `for` say run this `do-while` five time , `5*inf` :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your `do-while` loop. It will run till user guesses right code.
Insert following code to check length of string

```
if(s.length()!=5){
    System.out.println("code should be of length 5");
    continue;
}
```

You can add more restrictions for no characters in input string.
Also reset `x` at start of outer loop every time.

Also check if input string is correct in every outer loop

```
if(s.equals(num)){
    System.out.println("Congrats! You guessed the secret code. ");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: this is not true ! you must have exactly 5 chances !

Comment: you are ignoring a chance

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi If you are not giving correct number of characters, I guess still user is using an attempt

Answer (score 0):

***Current Code*** -

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    do {
         s = in.nextLine();
         for (int c = 0; c < s.length(); c++) { // the length of s can exceed 5 as of **num = "65854"**
             if (s.charAt(c) == num.charAt(c)) //if digit in 's' equals the digit in the same position in 'num', increment variable x
             x++;
             System.out.println("Number of correct digits in right position: " + x);
         }
      }
      while (!s.equals(num)); // this ensures currently N number of attempts NOT JUST 5 as stated otherwise.
      System.out.println("Congrats! You guessed the secret code. ");
      System.exit(0); // with this line the for loop would execute just once
}
```

***Suggested Code -***

```
String s;
int count = 0;
int x;
do {
    x = 0;
    if (count >= 5) { break; } // 5 attempts
    s = in.nextLine();
    String formattedNumber = String.format("%05d",
           Integer.parseInt(s)); // make sure the input is of 5 digit integer (padding here with 0's)
    for (int c = 0; c < formattedNumber.length(); c++) {
        if (formattedNumber.charAt(c) == num.charAt(c)) {
            x++;
        }
        if (x == 5) { // correct guess if all chars are equal
            System.out.println("Congrats! You guessed the secret code.");
            break; // break if guessed correct
        } else {
            System.out.println("Number of correct digits in right position: " + x);
        }
    }
    count++; //next attempt
} while (!s.equals(num)); //input not equals the desired, next attempt
```

Comment: Pro Tipp: Check for `count >= 5`.

Comment: @Fildor - could there be a change of `>` anyway?

Comment: Been there, done that. A co-worker changes the code, so count will skip "5". Then you run forever again ...

Comment: In this example it might not happen but when you have something like this in production code, you will spend hours stepping through code just to see that requirement was "at most 5" and you coded "not exactly 5" ...

Answer (score 0):

this code is gonna run for **EVER** since you enter the true code , because you have `do-while` that its condition say `!s.equals(num)` , so you must remove the `do-while` at first , it is not neccessary , when your predicted code is equal to the `num` then the variable `x` must equal to `5` , so you terminate your program using a `return` statement after the printing success. be aware of the value of `x` , it must be equal to zero at each iteration , i mean `x=0`!

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    s = in.nextLine();
    if(s.length!=5){
       System.out.println("code should be of length 5");
       continue;
    }
    x = 0;
    for(int c=0; c<5; c++){
       if(s.charAt(c)==num.charAt(c)) //if digit in 's' equals the digit in the same position in 'num', increment variable x
        x++;
    }
    System.out.println("Number of correct digits in right position: " + x);  // here the execution goes out of bounds
    if(x==5){
       System.out.println("Congrats! You guessed the secret code. ");
       return;
    }
}
System.out.println("Sryy !! :((");
```